# How to use sealed classes with generics?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-17, java-sealed-type

I have a parent abstract class and child classes which take generics.

```
public abstract sealed class Parent<T> permits ChildA, ChildB {}

public non-sealed class ChildA<T extends FileTypeA> extends Parent{}

public non-sealed class ChildB<T extends FileTypeB> extends Parent{}
```

In the parent class, I am getting warnings:

```
ChildA is a raw type. References to generic type ChildA<T> 
       should be parameterized

ChildB is a raw type. References to generic type ChildB<T> 
       should be parameterized
```

In the child classes, I am getting warnings:

```
Parent is a raw type. References to generic type Parent<T> 
       should be parameterized
```

Making them parameterized like this:

```
public abstract sealed class Parent<T> 
    permits ChildA<T extends FileTypeA>, ChildB<T extends FileTypeB> {}
```

Or even

```
public abstract sealed class Parent<T> 
    permits ChildA<T>, ChildB<T> {}
```

Gives the error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the 
    bounded parameter <T extends FileTypeA> of the type ChildA<T>
```

How to remove these warnings and errors?

Comment: Assuming you understand that you should not use raw types (the reason for your first warnings), the first thing you need to determine is the correct type argument in `extends Parent<...>`, and in that process answer the question why `Parent` is generic at all. That has nothing to do with sealed classes. With that solved, you can then try to answer the sealed class question about what type parameter to set in `permits ChildA<...>`. This is a good question, but I don't see anything that would be more meaningful than `... permits ChildA<?>, ChildB<?>`. Found nothing in the JLS.

Comment: @ernest_k I deduced the intention from the grammar. Since it doesn’t allow parameterized types after `permits` in the first place, the JLS authors might not have felt a need to discuss raw types vs parameterized types.

Comment: The Eclipse bug report for this is [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576378)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning “*Parent is a raw type*” is entirely unrelated to sealed classes, as using `extends Parent` when `Parent<T>` is a generic class will cause such a warning since Generics exist.

You most probably want to use

```java
public non-sealed class ChildA<T extends FileTypeA> extends Parent<T> {}

public non-sealed class ChildB<T extends FileTypeB> extends Parent<T> {}
```

The other issue seems to be an Eclipse bug, as I can only reproduce the warning there. When I change the declaration to `permits ChildA<?>, ChildB<?>`, the warning disappears, but you should *not* do this.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) defines the `permits` clause as

```
ClassPermits:
    permits TypeName {, TypeName}
```

whereas `TypeName` [is linked to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-TypeName)

```
TypeName:
    TypeIdentifier
    PackageOrTypeName . TypeIdentifier

PackageOrTypeName:
    Identifier
    PackageOrTypeName . Identifier
```

This clearly leads to a sequence of dot separated identifiers without any type parameters. Consistently, `javac` rejects a construct like `permits ChildA<?>, ChildB<?>`.

In other words, Eclipse should not generate a warning here and even more importantly, not accept parameterized types in a `permit` clause. Your best option is to wait for a fix of Eclipse’s Java 17 support. You could add a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` to the entire `Parent` class to make the warning go away, but since that would affect the entire class, I do not recommend it.

Comment: And my comment suggesting `permits ChildA<?>, ChildB<?>` was also based on a test done in Eclipse; `javac` rejects it. I just don't like this additional exception to the general "best practices" of using generic types as such. Good answer, +1.

Comment: @ernest_k don’t consider the types at this place as a raw types but having `<?>` always implied when necessary. Like method references of the form `List::add` are not raw, but inferring the necessary type from the context. I think, Java should have even more places where `<?[,?]*>` should be implied rather than falling back to raw types, e.g. `o instanceof List l` should behave the same as `o instanceof List<?> l`, as there is no need for this construct to be backward compatible with pre-Generics code.

Comment: Fair enough... except that `permits ChildA<?>` results in an error rather than a warning. But thank you for the insight.

Comment: @ernest_k right, that’s the consequence of being already ruled out by the grammar, as said in the answer. To me, this is a good thing. Since there’s no semantic difference between `ChildA` and `ChildA<?>` here, there’s only one valid form, the simpler one, and no long discussions about whether the former or the latter is to prefer, no time wasted to teach code formatters to convert one form into the other, to match the preference etc.