# Javadoc bug for sealed generic interface?

Tags: java, javadoc

The following code has javadoc produce an error, while the code compiles correctly. The minimal reproducible example consists of a sealed interface with a single implementation, both of which are generic.

The interface:

```
package mypackage;

/**
 * This is a sealed, generic interface. The only allowed implementation is
 * Class.
 */
public sealed interface Interface<T> permits Class<T> {
    // empty by design
}
```

The implementing class:

```
package mypackage;

/**
 * This is the only allowed implementation of Interface
 */
public final class Class<T> implements Interface<T> {
    // empty by design
}
```

Javadoc produces the following error message:

```
[...]\mypackage\Interface.java:7: error: '{' expected
public sealed interface Interface<T> permits Class<T> {
                                                  ^
```

This occurs whenever I try to create a sealed generic interface with a generic implementation, so I think it must be a bug. Any opinions?

Comment: Just to clarify: is that error produced by Javadoc (i.e. generating documentation) or by javac (i.e. compilation)?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? For me javac of Java 17 and Java 20 produces the exact same error as the javadoc tool. And IntelliJ shows an error _"Generics are not allowed in permits list"_ In other words, your permits list should simply be `permits Class`, not `permits Class<T>`. Why do you think this is valid syntax?

Comment: I believe @MarkRotteveel is right and it should be `sealed interface Interface<T> permits Class` together with `class Class<T> implements interface<T>`. take a look on the discussion here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491202/how-to-use-sealed-classes-with-generics

Comment: Funnily enough, when I'm running this in Eclipse it works and the IDE actually tells me that `permits C` should be parameterized (I used `interface I<T> permits C<T>` to reduce the impact of naming conflicts). Seems to be a difference in the compiler Eclipse is using.

Comment: The question linked by Emanuel links to an Eclipse bug reported in 2021, which still is not fixed: [Bug 576378 - \[compiler\] Wrong rawtype warning and wrong compilation of generic type reference in permits clause](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576378).

Comment: For completeness, the JLS states in [section 8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6): "ClassPermits: permits TypeName {, TypeName}" with "TypeName" just being the name without the type parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm developing in Eclipse, never thought the Eclipse compiler could be at fault. I will "revert" to the suggested solution of using raw types, even though the Eclipse compiler then annoyingly gives me a warning about that. @EmanuelTrandafir, if you wrap your comment into an answer I will approve it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are not allowed with the permits clause, therefore you should use the raw Class type in the first place:

```
sealed interface Interface<T> permits Class {}
```

and then, add the generic  type when you declare your class:

```
class Class<T> implements interface<T> {}
```

As @Mark Rotteveel suggested in the comments, the problem might be harder to spot in Eclipse due to this unfixed bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576378

Here is a more elaborate discussion about this topic: [How to use sealed classes with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491202/how-to-use-sealed-classes-with-generics)